# Can't rendering HTML main page in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I'm trying to connect Express backend to React frontend

```
Origin 
    >client
     >public
      >index.html
    >server
     >public
      >main.html
     >app.js
```

I seperated client & server folder. I wanted to show client/public/index.html(client side html) in /react route & public/main.html(server side html) in / route.
Same logic but client side static file works but server side doesn't work.

I referred to someone else's code so /users route specifies js file and it works fine.
But in localhost:4000/ (/ route) I always get 404 error. / route specifies index.js file in original code and I thought I disconnected it. But error page keeps pointing at index.js. I changed the relative path and kept looking for a way to render static files but it didn't work out.

Here is server side app.js code

```
var createError = require("http-errors");
var express = require("express");
var path = require("path");
var cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
var logger = require("morgan");

var indexRouter = require("./routes/index");
var usersRouter = require("./routes/users");

var app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
app.listen(port);

// view engine setup
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
app.set("view engine", "jade");

app.use(logger("dev"));
app.use(express.json());
var cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use("/", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
app.use("/react", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client/public")));

app.use("/users", usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get("env") === "development" ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render("error");
});
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "public/main.html"));
});
app.get("/react", function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "client/public/index.html"));
});
module.exports = app;
```

Server side main.html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/style.css" />

    <title>Home</title>
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 class="red">This is Home</h1>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Annotated index.js code

```
// var express = require("express");
// var router = express.Router();

// router.get("/", function (req, res, next) {
//   res.json([
//     {
//       id: 1,
//       username: "samsepi0l",
//     },
//     {
//       id: 2,
//       username: "D0loresH4ze",
//     },
//   ]);
// });

// module.exports = router;
```

Error page

```
Not Found
404
NotFoundError: Not Found
    at /Users/home/self/backtest/server/app.js:31:8
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/home/self/backtest/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/home/self/backtest/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /Users/home/self/backtest/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/Users/home/self/backtest/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/home/self/backtest/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at SendStream.error (/Users/home/self/backtest/server/node_modules/serve-static/index.js:121:7)
    at SendStream.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at SendStream.error (/Users/home/self/backtest/server/node_modules/send/index.js:270:17)
    at SendStream.onStatError (/Users/home/self/backtest/server/node_modules/send/index.js:421:12)
```

Comment: put `get("/", function(...)....)` above `app.use("/",express.static(...))`

Comment: @VasylMoskalov I've been trying for hours and it's solved in 10 sec Why didn't I think of it..? Thank you so much!